# VBA Close Excel File get subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running the below code and get the "subscript out of range" error on the workbook close line:

```
Sub SaveFileAs()
    With Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & filename).Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        .SaveAs path & "\" & "test.woe", _
                FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, _
                CreateBackup:=False
    End With

    Workbooks("test.woe").Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

However if i change `FileFormat:=xlTextWindows` into `FileFormat:=xlTextMac`, then I can close the file. I'm using windows 10. Can anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Working fine for me (running Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it - If I use

`FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS` then everything works as expected.